# ¿Cómo se analiza un archivo XML con SAX, cuando tiene etiquetas de mismo nombre pero en diferentes elementos?

Tags: java, xml, parsear

¡Buenas a todos!

Vengo de estar en stackoverflow en inglés pero todavía no hallo solución alguna a mi duda. He revisado algunos temas, [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209946/using-sax-parser-how-do-you-parse-an-xml-file-which-has-same-name-tags-but-in-d) principalmente, pero aún no me ha quedado claro. También la mayoría de preguntas similares tratan con DOM, pero al ser SAX más complicado no me ha servido de mucho.

Mi XML tiene una estructura similar a este ejemplo:

```
<root>
  <ejemplo1>
    <ejemplo1A>
      <dato1>Hello</dato1>
      <dato2>StackOwerflow</dato2>
      <dato3>
        <datoA>1</datoA>
        <datoB>2</datoB>
      </dato3>
      <dato4>
        <datoA>3</datoA>
        <datoB>4</datoB>
      </dato4>
      <dato5>
        <datoA>5</datoA>
        <datoB>6</datoB>
      </dato5>
    </ejemplo1A>
    <ejemploB>
      ...
    </ejemploB>
  </ejemplo1>
</root>
```

Mi programa se contruye con un Main, una clase donde almacena los datos de los objetos que voy a tratar y una clase para parser en SAX. A través de booleans he intentado "filtrar" pero igualmente me retorna null cuando desde el Main extraigo los datos para mostrarlos al usuario.

La clase del parser SAX tiene una estructura similar a este ejemplo:

```
public class parserSAX extends DefaultHandler{
   private ArrayList <EjemploClass> ejemploRes = new ArrayList<EjemploClass>();
   private EjemploClass ejemploObj = new EjemploClass();
   private int indicador = -1;
   private boolean dato3 = false, dato4 = false, dato5 = false;

   @Override
   public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
       if (qName.equals("ejemplo1A")){
          //Mucho else if para tratar los demás tags.
       }else if (qName.equals("dato3")){
          dato3 = true;
          if (qName.equals("datoA") && dato3) indicador = 1; 
          else if (qName.equals("datoB") && dato3) indicador = 2; 
       } else if (qName.equals("dato4")){
          //Similar a dato3
       } else if (qName.equals("dato5")){
          //Similar a dato3
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{
       if(qName.equals("ejemplo1A")){
        ejemploRes.add(this.ejemploObj); 
        ejemploObj = new EjemploClass();
       }

       if(qName.equals("dato3")){dato3 = false;}
       if(qName.equals("dato4")){dato4 = false;}
       if(qName.equals("dato5")){dato5 = false;}

       indicador = -1;
   }

   @Override
   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException{
       String char = new String(ch, start, length);
       if (indicador == 1){ ejemploObj.setDatoA_dato3(char);}
       else if (indicador == 2){ ejemploObj.setDatoB_dato3(char);}
       //Y más else if pero para los demás.
   }

   //Y un get para el ArrayList.
```

}

Soy consciente que aún no entiendo del todo cómo funciona el parser SAX, de hecho he intentado hacer otras chapuzas pero esta es la menos lamentable a mi parecer. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Estoy pensando en quitar los if else que están dentro de dato3, dato4 y dato5 para dejar el cambio del boolean pero luego no encuentro una alternativa para diferenciar datoA de datoB y por eso lo mantengo por el momento.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el fallo, y lo comparto por si alguna vez alguien llega al mismo punto que yo. Dicho error está en este método:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
 if (qName.equals("ejemplo1A")){
  //Mucho else if para tratar los demás tags.
 }else if (qName.equals("dato3")){
   dato3 = true;
   if (qName.equals("datoA") && dato3) indicador = 1; 
   else if (qName.equals("datoB") && dato3) indicador = 2; 
 } else if (qName.equals("dato4")){
  //Similar a dato3
 } else if (qName.equals("dato5")){
  //Similar a dato3
 }
}
```

Como lee de manera secuencial, cuando llega a los if donde la condición trata a dato3, dato4 o dato5 no entra dentro de los if donde comprueban datoA y datoB. Por lo tanto, hay que hacer dichas comprobaciones en el if global para que se efectue el evento asignado a esos datos. Es decir:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
   if (qName.equals("ejemplo1A")){
      //Mucho else if para tratar los demás tags.
   }else if (qName.equals("dato3")){
      dato3 = true;
   } else if (qName.equals("dato4")){
      //Similar a dato3
   } else if (qName.equals("dato5")){
      //Similar a dato3
   } else if (qName.equals("datoA") && dato3) indicador = 1; 
   } else if (qName.equals("datoB") && dato3) indicador = 2;
      //etc.
   }
}
```

Me explico muy mal, pero era simplemente por eso.